# How to set headers in RabbitMq with Scala

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka-stream, alpakka

Hi I'm trying to set headers in the rabbit messages with the library `akka-stream-alpakka-amqp` in scala but I can't be able to make it work and reading the repository I can't see any reference or method to add headers in the messages.

I was trying to add the headers property in the arguments but i can't make it work

```
val exchangeWitHeaders =
        RabbitIntegrationConstants.queueDeclaration.withArguments(Map("x-match" -> "all", "h1" -> "header"))
val writeSettings = AmqpWriteSettings(RabbitIntegrationConstants.connectionProvider)
        .withRoutingKey(RabbitIntegrationConstants.queueName)
        .withDeclaration(exchangeWitHeaders)

val amqpSinkExchange = AmqpSink.simple(writeSettings)
val textToSend = Vector("test")

Source(textToSend).map(s => ByteString(s)).runWith(amqpSinkExchange)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you will need to make sure that you are not using a `SimpleSink` so that it can accept a `WriteMessage` instead of a `ByteString`

```
val amqpSink = AmqpSink.apply(writeSettings)


Source(textToSend)
  .map { s =>
    val headers = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>()
    headers.put("header1", "value1")

    val basicProperties = 
      new BasicProperties.Builder()
        .headers(headers)
        .build()

    WriteMessage(ByteString(s))
      .withProperties(basicProperties)
  }
  .runWith(amqpSink)
```